# Проблема с INSERT запросом к полю с FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Помогите решить данную проблему.
в коде отметил комментарием поле, где выпадает ошибка.
Заранее спасибо!)текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом

```
CREATE TABLE Soldiers
    (
        SoldiersID int  NOT NULL
            PRIMARY KEY,
        SoldierName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
        SoldierSName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
        [Group] int  NOT NULL
    )
    GO
CREATE TABLE [Status]
(
    MSSTAT int UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    StatusName varchar(25) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE MSoldiers
(
    NUM INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    MSoldiersID int  NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY,
    MSoldiersName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    MSoldiersSName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    [Status] int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Status](MSSTAT),
    Weapon varchar(25)
)
GO




CREATE TABLE Main
(
    Soldier int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MSoldiers(MSoldiersID),
    MSoldier int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Soldiers(SoldiersID)
)
go


INSERT INTO [Status]
VALUES
(1, 'МАЙОР'),
(2, 'ПОДПОЛК')
GO


INSERT INTO MSoldiers
VALUES
(1, 'Буров', 'О.С.', 1, 'АК-47'),
(2, 'Рыюаков', 'Н.Г.', 1, 'Глок-20'),
(3, 'Деребаков', 'В.Я.', 2, 'АК-74')
GO


INSERT INTO Soldiers
VALUES
(205, 'Петров', 'В.А.', 222),
(221, 'Лодарев', 'П.С.', 232),
(201, 'Леонтьев', 'К.В.', 212),
(200, 'Дахов', 'Р.М.', 200)
go

INSERT INTO Main --ОШИБКА ТУТ!
VALUES
(205, 1), 
(205, 2),
(221, 3),
(221, 2),
(201, 1),
(201, 2),
(200, 1)
GO
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чуть подробнее, чем (правильный по сути) ответ Igor.

Либо поменяйте порядок столбцов:

```
INSERT INTO Main --ОШИБКА ТУТ!
VALUES
(1, 205), 
(2, 205),
...
GO
```

Либо явно укажите порядок, в котором вы всталяете столбцы:

```
INSERT INTO Main --ОШИБКА ТУТ!
(MSoldier, Soldier)
VALUES
(205, 1), 
(205, 2),
(221, 3),
(221, 2),
(201, 1),
(201, 2),
(200, 1)
GO
```

(Так меньше писанины, если вы всё это руками создавали и ошиблись)

Answer (score 3):

Перепутаны местами значения (и, похоже, что названия полей тоже).

Comment: @AK Наверное, Вы правы.